# How to calculate the IEEE 754 standard?

Tags: floating-point

I have to calculate the floating point backwards to the decimal.

the number is quit different (1 Bit Sign, 3 Bit exponent 6 Bit Mantisse)

1 | 101 | 100100

so i calculated it backwards and i got -6.4 
But i think this is wrong.

Calculation:

Sign 1 Means: its a negative number

Exponent: (101)5-3(011)= 2 the zero stands for the sign.

Mantisse: 1.100100 => 110.0100

110 = 6  and .0100 = 4

Answer: -6.4

Can you say me ami right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look up that standard, but a few things don't seem right.

First, your calculation of the exponent value is a bunch of hand waving, so it's hard to tell what you did.  In any case, a 3 bit exponent is probably in "excess 4" notation.  That means the field value is unsigned with 4 mapping to a exponent value of 0.  If so, your exponent value is actually 1 since the field value is 5.

Second, your statement that binary .0100 = decimal 4 is just plain wrong.  I have no idea how you got that.

You are assuming a implied 1 bit to the left of the mantissa, which is probably correct.  The raw mantissa value is therefore binary 1.100100.  After the exponent of 1 is applied, it becomes 11.00100, which is 3.125 in decimal.  Then applying the sign bit (thanks Wouter), the final result is -3.125.

Comment: AFAIK correct (I thought this in class a few years ago), but make that -3.125, because the sign bit is 1.

Comment: how do you get the exponent?

Comment: @Wouter: Oops, forgot about the sign bit.  Fixed.

Comment: @Fallout: Like I said, it is the exponent field value (interpreted as a unsigned integer) minus 4.

Comment: can you give me the calculation? 101 is in decimal 5 111 is in decimal 7 7-5 is 2 | or 5 - 3  is also 2

Comment: Read what Olin wrote: in IEEE the exponent is noted in 'excess-N', where N = 2^(number-of-bits-minus-one). For your 3 bits hence excess-4. 0x101 is 5, which is 1 in excess of 4, so the exponent is +1.